# Referencing an external class from a Jersey REST web app

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying a simple example of creating a RESTful API. I used the Maven `jersey-quickstart-webapp` archtype to create a Jersey web app. In a **separate project** I created a simple class: `SimpleClass`, which only has one method that returns "hello". I am trying to create an instance of that class in my method in the web app (I am using the default `MyResource` class) and call its method to get "Hello". I exported the project with the `SimpleClass` to a JAR file, and added that file to the build path for my Jersey project, and imported the relevant package. 
When I run the web app on a local server, and call the `MyResource` method, I get an error with the root cause (just the top few rows):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/test/simple/SimpleClass;
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
```

So, it can't find the SimpleClass class. 
What am I doing wrong here? I'd really appreciate any help!
Thanks,
Yariv.

New info: I tried to create a RESTful web service without Maven. I successfully created the project with a simple "Hello World" example, and then I tried to add my own class from another project: I imported the .jar, added it to the build path, and created a class in the web service that creates an instance of my class when a GET is made to the server. My class happens to include (as members) instances of other classes, one of which connects to a MongoDB database, and when I run the service, I again get a HTTP 500 error as follows:
A `MultiException` has 2 exceptions.  They are:

```
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.notes.server.NotesServer
```

Adding the MongoDB jar to the web project did not help. I must be missing something big here. What should I do to call code I created in another project (with a set of dependencies there) in my web service?

I'll appreciate any help I can get, I am getting nowhere with this...

Comment: how exactly do you "run the web app on a local server" ? did you place your lib jar (containing SimpleClass) in that server's classpath? its not enough to compile against a library, you also need that library available to you at runtime.

Comment: What I did is start a local Tomcat server, right-clicked the Jersey project and selected Run As -> Run on Server.
How do I add the JAR to the server's classpath?

Comment: i suspect the issue is that youre using a maven project, but instead of adding your library as a maven dependency you added it as a dependency "in the IDE layer" (eclipse? idea?). try adding the dependency "properly" (in the webapp's pom.xml file) and see if the deployment logic picks it up

Comment: absolute worst-case you could place your lib jar into tomcats lib folder - see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html - but that would be a bad solution.

Comment: I tried adding the dependancy in the pom.xml as follows and I still get the same error:
<dependency>
         <groupId>SimpleClass</groupId>
         <artifactId>SimpleClass</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <type>jar</type>
         <systemPath>/Users/myusername/dev/service/src/lib/SimpleClass.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
I am using Eclipse, by the way. Any ideas? I don't get an error when viewing the pom.xml file that it can't find this path, so I guess it can find the JAR.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm not getting the hang of how this comment box works... I keeping hitting Enter and it keeps submitting the comment when I just want a new line...

Comment: system dependencies (apart from being a generally horrible thing to be used only as last resort) wont work because they wont be deployed alongside your project (system deps are assumed to just be there on the classpath at run time - see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).
you need to make a jar library out of that class, and add a dependency on that library. i suggest you read a quickstart on maven https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve all these issues by adding all the relevant JARs to the deployment assembly (right-click on the project, click Properties, then select Deployment Assembly and add all the JARs that my class depends on, as well as its own JAR).
Thanks for your help, radai!

Comment: im glad it worked out for you, but i still think the pom is the right place to add the dependencies to :-)